# How to change .show() to a .toggle() without duplicating items in my function(how can I refactor)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am currently working in my first backbone.js app.  I made a "show comment" function that renders a view in an underscore.js template and renders it to my view.  The problem is, I want to "toggle" all the comments when a button is clicked, not just "show" commentView. How can I refactor this "showComment" function to not duplicate the current view? The success callback iterates over each comment in the comment view and then renders it. Using toggle, I would like it to just render 1 view, not render the same view, multiple times on each click when clicking toggle.

Example:

User clicks the show comments button, 5 comments are displayed.

User clicks  the show comments button, comments are hidden.

User clicks the show comments button, 10 comments are displayed (the first 5 and since the success function renders a whole new view, the first 5 questions initially displayed are appended to the first 5, so there are 10 total now).

Here is the main function

```
 showComments: function() {
      this.commentsView = this.$el.find(".comments_container");
      this.commentsView.show(); ***INSTEAD OF .show() I CAN USE .TOGGLE() but I get DUPLICATES WHENEVER THE VIEW IS RENDERED ***
      this.commentCollection = new app.CommentList();
      // // debugger;
      var self = this;
      this.commentCollection.fetch({
        data: { question_id: this.$el.attr('question_id') },
        success: function(collection) {
          collection.each(function(comment) {
            var commentView = new app.CommentView({model: comment});
            var html = commentView.render().el;
            self.commentsView.append(html);
          });
        }
      });
```

Here is the backbone Event:

```
'click .show_comments': 'showComments'
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a few ways that you could do it.

You could render and hide the comment view on page load and then bind the button commentsView.toggle.

OR in your showComments function you can have an evaluation that checks to see if the commentsView is already created.

```
If (this.commentView != null)
  //toggle
else
  //create your view and show it
```